# Frequência Percentual no R com dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Estava querendo utilizar o pacote dplyr para calcular a Frequência Relativa por grupo. Tenho uma base de dados como as três primeiras colunas abaixo e gostaria que a última coluna fosse a variável resposta:

```
CNPJ    Central             depositos   Resultado final
315406  SICOOB CECRESP      4,61E+13    97,78%
512839  SICOOB CECRESP      1,05E+12    2,22%
68987   SICOOB CREDIMINAS   5,22E+13    33,00%
429890  SICOOB CREDIMINAS   3,88E+13    24,54%
803287  SICOOB CREDIMINAS   3,82E+13    24,15%
804046  SICOOB CREDIMINAS   2,90E+13    18,31%
694877  SICOOB PLANALTO CENTRAL 5,01E+13    100,00%
694389  SICOOB SC/RS        8,75E+13    67,28%
707903  SICOOB SC/RS        4,25E+13    32,72%
```

Alguma sugestão? Não conheço muito o pacote dplyr mas fiz algumas tentativas frustradas como:

```
dados <- dados %>% 
  group_by(CENTRAL, depositos) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(csum = cumsum(value))
```

E a Frequência Relativa Acumulada por CENTRAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar isso:

```
dados %>% 
    group_by(Central, depositos) %>% 
    mutate(freq_relat=Resultado/sum(Resultado)) %>%  
    mutate(freq_relat=round(freq_relat*100, 2))
```

Comment: Rafael, o que você consideraria para fazer a Frequência Relativa Acumulada?

Comment: Oi Veiga, eu seguiria no pipe e usaria o `cumsum` : `mutate(freq_cum=cumsum(value)/sum(value))` .

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para dar um feedback, a partir da programação do Rafael, a programação que calculou a frequência relativa foi:

```
  dados<-dados %>% 
     group_by(CENTRAL) %>% 
     mutate(freq_relat=depositos/sum(depositos)) %>%  
     mutate(freq_relat=round(freq_relat*100, 2))
```